# Check if multiple cookies are active

Tags: jquery, cookies

I just need to check whether multiple cookies are active in an if statement, and by active I mean if they're in the clients local cookies.

```
$(function() {
    if ($.cookie('setting7') == null && $.cookie('setting6') == null) {
        // client doesn't have local cookies
    } else {
        alert('client has cookies')
    };
});
```

I've tries using this, but the alert shows up if just one is enabled

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So simple change the condition to `||`, you are comparing with `and`, but you need `or`:

```
$(function() {
    if ($.cookie('setting7') == null || $.cookie('setting6') == null) {
        // client doesn't have local cookies
    } else {
        alert('client has cookies')
    };
});
```

Comment: Ah that was simple, using the && just seemed like it made more sense. Thanks! I'll remember that one.